# How to override internal classes with inline styles in React?

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

I have a container. Inside it is some out of the box component. This component has a set of `CSS` classes defined. I want to override them based on class names with some values calculated within my outermost component.

Example:

```
const someComponent = ({someProp}) => {
       return (
              <div style={{hereIWantToTargetSomeCSSClass: someProp}}>
                     <ThisIsOutOfTheBoxComponent />
              </div>);
}
```

Let's suppose that `ThisIsOutOfTheBoxComponent` has class `.internal-bg` with `background-color` set as black.

I want to override this class and set the value of `background-color` as `someProp` value.

Is it feasible?

If it's not then how to achieve the same result with different means?

Comment: can you write a stylesheet and use a more specific style and/or `!important`?

Comment: How can I inject value of prop to stylesheet?

Comment: What are u using for CSS? CSS in JS or something else? And is it like you know there is a class internal-bg inside that component or it can be anything you just added it as example?

Comment: SCSS imported by "./styles.scss"

Comment: Example :). Real world it's

.rc-slider-handle:active {
  border-color: #57c5f7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #57c5f7;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}

Comment: you could add class name that changes based on a prop then target that, you could write an inline stylesheet using `<style>` tags and mod your css there. you could get at the element with js, etc.

Comment: @imjared Actually now I'm doing this because I couldn't find any other way. But it's just a partial solution because we have limited amount of values coming from prop. In my case it's actually limited to two values so it's even reasonable, but in general - it you'd like to pass color in hex... Well...